# How to : numerical integration by quadrature in C language / remove NaN

Tags: quadrature, numerics, integration

What I wanna solve it the problem following
( by quadrature method )
[image]

I want to get two arrays of data ( z & tau )
from z[0], tau[0] to z[2249], tau[2249].

Since the integrand diverges at z=0.9, 1.125, I need to tame the divergence, but firstly, I want to make simple scheme of my program.

Following is my C language code of numerical integration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
int Narray;
int k;
Narray = 2250;
double zeta[Narray];
double dzeta = 0.225/Narray;
double tau[Narray];
zeta[0]=0.9;
tau[0]=0;

for (k=1; k<Narray-1 ; k++){
    zeta[k]=zeta[k-1]+dzeta;
    tau[k]=tau[k-1]+dzeta*zeta[k]/sqrt(0.987654*(zeta[k]-0.9)*(9/8-zeta[k]));
    printf("zeta = %lf tau = %lf \n", zeta[k], tau[k]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile the code in ubuntu, NaN appears as result...

Also, datas were different from the calculation by Wolframalpha.

( I've sampled few points and compared with Wolfram alpha. )

[image]

I suppose problem occurs at the equation of zeta...
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Haven't checked the rest but 9/8 is an integer expression and so returns an integer which will be 1. Try 9.0/8.0, and also understand why this is important.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the basic concept that what I usually say 9/8 is not the same to computer...

Comment: NaN disappeared and What's left is just taming improper integration over 0.9 to 0.9+dzeta. And I will try this one myself . Thank you again!

Comment: @IanBush if you write your comment as answer user501175 can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't checked the rest but 9/8 is an integer expression and so returns an integer which will be 1. Try 9.0/8.0, and also understand why this is important.